# Flutter webrtc Failed to set remote answer sdp

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I am  trying to connect two peer in flutter webrtc but i am getting below error.I am using firebase as a signalling server.

```
  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to RTCPeerConnection::setRemoteDescription: peerConnectionSetRemoteDescription(): WEBRTC_SET_REMOTE_DESCRIPTION_ERROR: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
```

I  am using below code in listening to the changes in firebase

```
         if (val['t'] == "ans") {
            assert(isInitiator);
            _peerCon.setRemoteDescription(
              RTCSessionDescription(
                val['sdp'],
                val['tp'],
              ),
            );
            return;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

One peer connection can only set **one** remote description.

You are trying to `setRemoteDescription` on a peer with an already established connection. That's why you getting this error.

Check this thread for more details:
[Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062565/failed-to-set-remote-answer-sdp-called-in-wrong-state-stable)